# Symfony2.2 Swiftmailer not working in AWS-EC2 Server Site

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpmyadmin, php-5.3

I am working on a symfony 2.2 project Site in which I am using swift mailer for sending the mail ; 
In Parameter.yml , configuration is as follows:

```
database_driver:   pdo_mysql
database_host:     localhost
database_port:     null
database_name:     My_Project_Name
database_user:     username
database_password: userpass

mailer_transport:  gmail
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_encryption: ssl
mailer_auth_mode:  login
mailer_user:       my_user_name@gmail.com
mailer_password:   my_gmail_account_password

locale:            en
secret:            my_secret
database_path:     null
```

and my mailer is as follows:

```
       $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject("Subject_description")
        ->setFrom("my_user_name@gmail.com")
        ->setTo("destination_email@maildomain.com")
        ->setBody("message_body");

    $this->mailer->send($message);
```

It's working perfectly in localhost but when project site is live on AWS-EC2 server ,it is giving no error and giving the notification message about successes fully sending the mail but in actually no email is being received on destination_email@maildomain.com. I do't know what configuration is wrong with me ?

If any body has idea about this problem please let me know , it will be very much appreciated !

Comment: Have you tried checking into the spam folder of your mail? Aws ip are usually blacklisted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extracting my mind through many help links i finally found the solution as given below :

```
# app/config/parameter.yml
swiftmailer:
transport:  smtp
host:       email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
username:   AWS_ACCESS_KEY
password:   AWS_SECRET_KEY
encryption: tls
port:       25
```

and in Mailer :

```
 $renderedLines = explode("\n", trim($renderedTemplate));
    $subject = $renderedLines[0];
    $body = implode("\n", array_slice($renderedLines, 1));
    $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance( 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', 
    25, 
    'tls')->setUsername('aws_key')->setPassword('aws_secret');
    $innerMailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('My_Project_Title_Subject')
        ->setFrom(array('my_mail@domail.com' => 'Reference Name'))
        ->setTo("destination_mail@domail.id")
        ->setBody($body, 'text/html');

    $innerMailer->send($message);
```

It's working finally !

hopes it will help someone !